# Diferencias entre el push, pull y update de github

Tags: github, update, git-push, git-pull

Hola estoy haciendo un trabajo colaborativo sobre una pagina web con amigos usando github, pero el problema que tenemos es que por ejemplo una vez uno de mis amigos le hizo push y merge a su parte del proyecto pero no tenia lo de los otros, entonces cuando otro amigo hizo el update todo se combino y perdimos partes del proyecto, aun seguimos por eso pedimos que alguien nos explique como podemos trabajar para tener menos problemas que recomendaciones nos dan para el mejor uso del github y verlo como una ventaja mas que un problema.

Gracias

Comment: Ven a la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Mientras tanto, play: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CK5ZcKZsMRs

Comment: Para eso GitHub tiene una característica de hacer pull request. Aparte de revisar lo que otro compañero hace, el mismo pipeline te limita a subir cambios si hay merge conflicts.